# Base Controller inheritance in ASP.NET Core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I just started my first project in asp net core and I migrate from .Net framework.

I created a new project using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and I added Identity via

```
Right click on project -> Add -> Add scaffolded items
```

to my project.

First of all something make me confused. All of the files for identification moved to an area called Identity and Manage section files moved to Account folder. Most important thing is I don't have the account and manage controllers

I created a new empty controller called `BaseController`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _db { get; set; }

    public BaseController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string userEmail = User.Identity.Name;                
            ViewBag.CurrentUser = _db.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(userEmail)).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

In this controller I get the logged in user and pass it to a ViewBag and show it in my view.

I have a `HomeController` that inherits from `BaseController`:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager { get; set; }
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
                          ApplicationDbContext db) : base (db)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

This part of code works fine but when I try to navigate to `Manage/Index` or `Manage/ChangePassword` I get this error and I don't know how can I resolve this problem. The cause of this error is ViewBag is empty because the base controller action never run.

Sorry if my question is simple and is not professional

Comment: Did you make sure that the authentication is happening? Unless the controller requires authentication the HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated may not be set and thus no ViewBag value.  Adding the [Authorize] attribute to the controller method or controller class will enforce the request to be authenticated which will set the user Identity.

Comment: @Rentering.com In the home controller authentication works. when I start the project on the navbar menu I can see my authorized email and full name and I can log out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net core 2.1, scaffold Identity uses [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) rather than MVC structure, so there is no controllers in `Identity` area and you could not inherit controller. Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-web-app-with-authentication).

Since it is in area, you need to use url like `https://localhost:44367/Identity/Account/Manage/Index` or `https://localhost:44367/Identity/Account/Manage/ChangePassword`to access the Razor Pages.

Besides, `ViewBag` is not supported in Razor Pages, you could use `ViewData` instead, refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2#weakly-typed-data-viewdata-viewdata-attribute-and-viewbag).

For adding filters for Razor Pages, you could refer to [Filters in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters)

```
public class BasePageModel : PageModel
{
    public override void OnPageHandlerExecuting(PageHandlerExecutingContext context)
    {
        //...
    }
}
public class IndexModel : BasePageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Xing_Zou. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Xing_Zou great point on ViewData, I missed that very important point about ViewBag.